# The target entry-point "@ionic-native/sqlite" has missing dependencies en IONIC 5 ANGULAR CAPACITOR

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, capacitor

Error que da en IONIC 5 ANGULAR CAPACITOR, primero probe con CORDOVA pero me da el mismo problema. Les agradeceria que me ayudaran a encontrar el problema. El error se da cuando ejecuto IONIC CAPACITOR RUN ANDROID con un emulador fisico.

[image: ESTE ES EL ERROR QUE ME DA]

Answer (score 0):

SOLUCIÓN:

npm install --save @ionic-native/core

Lo que sucede es que para poder usar SQLite nativo antes debes instalar el plugin Ionic Native Core, ya que SQLite nativo depende de Native Core